# Check if certain programs are installed

Tags: linux

I have this problem that i am trying to figure out a way how to check if some certain programs/tools are installed on my machine and if they are not, it would install it (only if it is not there)

For an example, we have `nmap` or `dc` or even `git`
These are just examples.

Currently, i have my own script where i have to write the `apt-get update` and `apt-get install TOOL/PROGRAM-Name` to install the tool/program.

There are probably some if statements required? im not sure. any suggestions?

> EDIT. Made a new post as i googled and found a half script that does it.

Comment: Can't you run `apt-get install` unconditionally?

Comment: What you are saying is that i can simply write all i want to install and just let it be there in the script?, im just alittle worried that maybe it might do something bad if it does it over and over and over again.

Comment: Then why do you want to automate the process?

Answer (score 2):

To find out if nmap is installed, you could do:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep nmap
```

To install nmap:

```
apt-get install nmap
```

So, to check if nmap is installed and install it if it isn't, you could do the following:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep nmap || apt-get install nmap
```

On CentOS, that would be:

```
rpm -qa | grep nmap || yum install nmap
```